# How to read tag and their related triggers name/ value in google analytics 4 using java

Tags: java, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am using [GA4 tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries?hl=en_GB) to make an API call to `Google Analytics 4`and the code provided in that link is listing my data based on defined dimension and metrics.Suppose in `Google Tag Manager`, I have created a tag and relative triggers like in this photo:  [image: Tag Trigger]
For example if the user clicks on the menu bar and the `Click URL` contains specific URL, then the tag is fired. Of course it is possible to see this information from  [Google Tag Assistant](https://tagassistant.google.com/).
[image: My variables in Google Tag Assistant, while the tag is triggered]
Now I want to know if it is possible to list these tags and triggers using `JAVA` as well or not?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out how to do it. As an example for the tag and trigger I created:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataSettings;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.DateRange;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.Dimension;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportRequest;
import com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.RunReportResponse;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

import io.grpc.LoadBalancerRegistry;
import io.grpc.grpclb.GrpclbLoadBalancerProvider;

public class Ga4DataAnalytics2 {

    static {
        LoadBalancerRegistry.getDefaultRegistry().register( new GrpclbLoadBalancerProvider());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String credentialsJsonPath="path to credential.json";
    String propertyId = "your property ID";
    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(credentialsJsonPath).getParent());

    GoogleCredentials credentials =
            GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialsJsonPath));

    BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =
            BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
            .build();    

    try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData =
            BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings)) {
        RunReportRequest request =
                RunReportRequest.newBuilder()
                .setProperty("properties/" + propertyId)
                .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("linkUrl"))
                .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("linkText"))          
                .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate("2022-09-25").setEndDate("2022-09-26"))
                .build();
        RunReportResponse response = analyticsData.runReport(request);
        System.out.println("Report result:\n"+response);
     
    }

}

}
```

and why I am using `linkUrl` and `linkText` as dimensions, that is because my tag configuration was :
[image: My Tag Configuration]